# Few main variables in the best model still show multicollineairty. Should I remove them despite their importance?

Tags: regression, interaction, centering

I have a binary logistic regression with 5 IVs and all of their 2-way interactions. I have reduced/removed multicollinearity between main variables and their interactions by centering the main variables. I have found one of the best models according to LRT. The model also accords reasonably with theory. Everything is fine.

However, one of the odds ratios is very large and its 95% CI is strangely super-broad. I think this is caused by a new case of multicollinearity. This OR is for a main variable which is highly correlated (> 0.8) with a couple of other main variables, according to the correlation matrix.

What do you suggest me to do with this new source of multicollinearity which happens to be one of the main variables in this research?

1. Should I remove it from the model and analyze it in isolation?
2. Should I report it as is, but discuss that the very large OR is a case of multicollinearity?
3. Should I report it as is, but add its isolated analysis as well?

Do you have any other suggestions that is routinely done in the case of a resisting multicollinearity?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: i) Try to find out the tolerance or variance inflation factor among the predictors, you can usually get those from linear regression module. ii) In logistic regression there is another possibility that you probably should also check. If your IV contains some categorical variables, compounded by the interactions, you may have some cells that are of zero counts. In that case, the standard error of the predictor's tends to be inflated.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) but my problem is not "whether or not this variable is causing multicollinearity or not". I already know that it is causing it. I don't know how to treat it. I don't know whether I should remove it from my model or should do what?

Comment: What does the major exposure of interest interact with? It'd be helpful if you can show the model (variable name and p-value).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd love to but can't (due to confidentiality). I am reporting both the model in which small problems exist and the one in which I have removed the problematic variable. I would discuss both of them afterward.